# Can't Launch Neo4J on OS X Yosemite - Issue with slf4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, slf4j, osx-yosemite

I have tried running Neo4j from both the most recent download folder (neo4j-community-2.1.6) and from a Homebrew installation (community 2.0.0). In each case, I get the following error:

```
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew -Djava.awt.headless=true
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [2411]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

So, I go to the log (`/data/log/console.log`) and get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(ConfigurationUtils.java:447)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
```

My $JAVA_HOME is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Output of /usr/libexec/java_home -V is:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.7.0_51, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_15, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In /Library/Java/Extensions I have:

```
logback-classic.jar@ -> /usr/local/xuggler/share/java/jars/logback-classic.jar
logback-core.jar@    -> /usr/local/xuggler/share/java/jars/logback-core.jar
slf4j-api.jar@       -> /usr/local/xuggler/share/java/jars/slf4j-api.jar
xuggle-xuggler.jar@  -> /usr/local/xuggler/share/java/jars/xuggle-xuggler.jar
```

I tried updating `/usr/local/xuggler/share/java/jars/slf4j-api.jar` to the most recent version, but then a new error appears in the console.log saying that version 1.5.6 is expected, but was not found. So, I put the original back.

I'm running OS X 10.10.1. `uname -a`:

```
Darwin xxxxxxx.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

If anyone can give me any advice as to how to get this running, I would be most appreciative.

Thank you!
james